# Multiple slick issue

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

I have a multiple slick sliders on the page with different amount of item in them.
Slick slider must initiate if length of items are >= 3. And I can't find out how to resolve this.
Here is the code example:

```
<div class="diploma-carousel">
 <div class="diploma-carousel-list">
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="diploma-carousel-list">
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="diploma-carousel-list">
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
  <div class="diploma-carousel-item">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
 $('.diploma-carousel-list').each(function(item) {
     let sliderItems = $(this).find('.diploma-carousel-item');
     let sliderItemsLength = sliderItems.length;
     if (sliderItemsLength >= 3) {
        $(this).parent().closest().slick();
     }
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$(this)` in your function is the element with the CSS class `.diploma-carousel-list` from the current iteration of your `each()` loop.
- `$(this).parent()` therefore is the container with the CSS class `.diploma-carousel`.
- `$(this).parent().closest()` would be the ancestor of `<div class="diploma-carousel">` (not shown in your sample code)

As you probably want to apply the Slick Slider directly to the `diploma-carousel-list` element, just using `$(this).slick();` instead of `$(this).parent().closest().slick();` should do the trick.

EDIT:
`$(this).parent().closest()` selects absolutely nothing, as `closest()` travels up the DOM and returns the first element - including the current element - *that matches the given selector*. Using `closest()` without any arguments simply returns an empty jQuery object. See https://api.jquery.com/closest/ for further information.